# Solving equation in a form x(alnx + b) = c for x using Lambert W function

Tags: lambert-w

I don't know how to solve an equation in a form of x(alnx + b) = c for x using Lambert W function. a, b and c stand for constants. I tried using Wolfram Alpha, but it does not provide step by step solution. Any comments will be welcomed.

Kind regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, I don't fully undestand what is unclear here. I checked this with Wolfram Alpha and it provided me a proper solution in terms of a, b and c (and also e) using the Lambert W function. Unfortunately, it didn't provide step by step solution for some reason. This is what I'm asking - step by step solution for this equation.